# How do you check the type of an array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, types

Assuming the array I'm trying to check is a simple array of a single type, how do you check the type of this array?

I've tried doing

```js
let arr1: number[] = [1,2,3,4,5];

console.log(typeof arr1[0] === "number"); // logs true
```

This works, but if an array is empty, like so:

```js
let arr2: number[] = [];

console.log(typeof arr2[0] === "number"); // logs false
```

this method doesn't hold up.

My question is two-fold: Is there a better way to do this? If so, does it hold up for empty arrays as well?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-dev.20201224#code/PTAEDkHsDsFoFMC2AHALgT1AQwE46+gDSioAWAlgM6imQA2AJtQK7IB0AUB3fKtngEYAXKGjNEAI3g4A2gF1QAXlAyBhAEyEAzIQAshAKxyA3FwDGMSvXhs6kAOYAKDMniQAZvxwCZABgWKgaAARGKS0sEAlKYcIKAAoigYXgTEZFSgDJDwlNAA5Hy0jKCsnDx8uDjqImFSsgEqJuaW1rYOzuiuHl7qfgFBoeJ1UcZAA) with the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for doing this approach with javascript arrays "from the box". You have only these tools:

- static type checking in Typescript
- `typeof`/`Array.isArray` which can check the fact either object is Array or not

There are different tools for runtime type checking in javascript: e.g. [type-check](https://gkz.github.io/type-check/). But if you use Typescript and have a string contract with a data source then you probably don't need such tools.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by static type checking?

Comment: @grian typescript is statically-typed, thereby it provides static typing through type annotations to enable type checking at (and only) compile time

Comment: ah I see what you mean now, I should've probably mentioned this in the original post, but my input array is of type `any[]`(which is bad practice but as this is a personal project I don't particularly care), so I need to check the type of the input array for one of my functions, which is why your answered confused me.